# Google Apps New Sub Company -> Mobile Setup

Tags: gmail, google-apps

We have just setup a Google Apps domain for email and I'd like to add a sub company domain to our account... now this seems straight forward and easy to setup the only question I do have which I can't find the answer is is how do I setup another domain on a mobile / outlook / imail?

Is it just as simple as adding another google account using the new domain.com email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're looking to do. Google Apps allows you to manage multiple domains from one Apps account. Details on this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182452).

Can you clarify the bit about setting up another domain on a mobile or client? If you mean your domain is example.com and you've added a secondary domain of example2.com where you have some users @example2.com rather than @example.com, it's as simple as setting up the device/client with the same account credentials as they use to sign into the web UI.

I'm not sure if the above is what you're looking for. Please clarify if I've missed the mark :)